# I do no harm unless harmed

Tags: riddle, word

> When I am alive, I do not speak
>
> When I am taken captive, my head is cut off
>
> They bite my bare body
>
> I do no harm, unless they cut me first
>
> Then I shall soon make them cry

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are an

> Onion

When I am alive, I do not speak

> Onions don't talk

When I am taken captive, my head is cut off

> People tend to only take the "head" of the onion

They bite my bare body

> People eat onions after peeling the skin off ("bare body")

I do no harm, unless they cut me first
Then I shall soon make them cry

> Onions are known to make people cry when they are cut